# OpenTK C# artifact on the texture

Tags: opentk

I'm start learning OpenGL and find a problem with my texture. I have a clear texture in png format, which I set on the quad. After testing I found some strange lines.

How I can remove that lines?
[Image with bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RZvC.png)

Draw scene:

```cs
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureId);
GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);

GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads);

GL.TexCoord2(new Vector2(0, 0));            GL.Vertex2(new Vector2(0, 0));
GL.TexCoord2(new Vector2(0.125F, 0));       GL.Vertex2(new Vector2(size.Width, 0));
GL.TexCoord2(new Vector2(0.125F, -1));      GL.Vertex2(new Vector2(size.Width, size.Height));
GL.TexCoord2(new Vector2(0, -1));           GL.Vertex2(new Vector2(0, size.Height));

GL.End();

GL.Disable(EnableCap.Blend);
```

---

Register texture:

```cs
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path);
int texture = 0;

GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);

GL.GenTextures(1, out texture);
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texture);
GL.TexEnv(TextureEnvTarget.TextureEnv, TextureEnvParameter.TextureEnvMode, (float)TextureEnvMode.Modulate);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);

BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba, data.Width, data.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);

bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the Texture gets repeated. If a texture coodinate is  not in the range 0 to 1 OpenGL "takes" the color of the "opposite side". The artifacts then appear due to calculation imprecision.

You might try setting the two texture parameters

```
TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS
TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT
```

to

```
TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge
```

Using GL.TexParameter()

Also consider to replace the -1 with 1.